# ¿Por que no me registra el empleado en mysql desde php?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este formulario para registrar un empleado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="EstiloEmpleados.Css">
    <style media="screen">
    .enviar{
      margin-left: 80px;
    }
    .apellidos{
      margin-left: 47px;
    }
    .sueldo{
      margin-left: 65px;
    }
    .banner{
      position: relative;
      margin-left: 500px;
    }
    .cargo{
      margin-left: 70px;
    }
    h1{
      background-color: yellow;
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
    form{
      margin: auto;
      position: absolute;
    }
      .identificacion{
        margin-left: 22px; }
      .nombre{margin-left: 57px;}
    </style>
    <title>Insertar empleado</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>AGREGAR EMPLEADO</h1><br><br>
    <div class="banner">
    <form class="formulario" action="validarFormulario.php" method="POST">
    <h2></h2>  Identificación:
      <input class="identificacion" type="text" name="identificacion" value=""> <br><br>
      Nombre:
      <input class="nombres" type="text" name="nombres" value="">
      <br><br>
      Apellidos:
      <input class="apellidos"type="text" name="apellidos">
      <br><br>
      Cargo:
      <select class="cargo" name="cargo" style="width:148px">
      <option name="opcion" value="0">Elige una opción</option>
      <option name="gerente" value="Gerente">Gerente</option>
      <option name="contador" value="Contador">Contador</option>
      <option name="mesero" value="mesero">Mesero</option>
      </select><br><br>
      Sueldo:
      <input class="sueldo" type="text" name="sueldo" value="">
      <br><br>
      <input class="enviar" type="submit" name="" value="Enviar">
    </form>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

luego tengo un archivo php para insertar datos. Antes tengo un array php para comprobar que los datos del formulario si los recibe:

```
    <?php
require "conexion.php";
extract($_REQUEST);
 echo '<PRE>'; print_r($_REQUEST);

$conexion=conectarse();
$cargo=$_POST['cargo'];
if ($cargo=='gerente') {
  $cargo='gerente';
} if($cargo=='mesero') {
   $cargo='mesero';
}
if($cargo=='contador'){
  $cargo='contador';
}
$sql="insert into empleados(identificacion,nombres,apellidos,cargo,sueldo)
values('$_REQUEST[identificacion]','$_REQUEST[nombre]','$_REQUEST[apellidos]','$_REQUEST[cargo]',''$_REQUEST[sueldo]')";

$resultado2=$conexion->query($sql);

if($resultado2) echo "El empleado ha sido registrado exitosamente";
else echo "No se ha podido registrar el empleado";
 ?>
```

No me registra el empleado.

Comment: `$_REQUEST[nombres]` Te faltan las **s**.

Comment: Deberías blindar más el código. Cuando haces `$resultado2=$conexion->query($sql);` no compruebas el resultado de la consulta, por lo que eres ajeno al error SQL que te está provocando una consulta incorrecta. PD: ¿Usas PDO o mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

Se ven un par de cosas en la creación de la query:

```
$sql="insert into empleados(identificacion,nombres,apellidos,cargo,sueldo)
values('$_REQUEST[identificacion]','$_REQUEST[nombre]','$_REQUEST[apellidos]','$_REQUEST[cargo]',''$_REQUEST[sueldo]')";
```

La primera es que tienes una `'` de más justo antes de `$_REQUEST[sueldo]`. Si la quitas posiblemente funcione correctamente.

La segunda es que estás entrecomillando los distintos `$_REQUEST[variable]` entre comillas simples `'` por lo que es probable que se **interprete como valor literal y no sustituya por su valor** o contenido, es decir, que te va a insertar `$_REQUEST[variable]` en vez de su valor y aquí te puede fallar por tipos de datos de la columna.